# Pandas How does the corrwith() work in this funcrion?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

The Function is to find the correlation of any store with another store
input=store number which is to be compared
output=dataframe with correlation coefficient values

````
def calcCorr(store):
    a=[]
    metrix=pre_df[['TOT_SALES','TXN_PER_CUST']]```#add metrics as required e.g. 
    ,'TXN_PER_CUST'

    for i in metrix.index:
        a.append(metrix.loc[store].corrwith(metrix.loc[i[0]]))

    df= pd.DataFrame(a)

    df.index=metrix.index

    df=df.drop_duplicates()

    df.index=[s[0] for s in df.index]

    df.index.name="STORE_NBR"

    return df
````

I dont' understand this part `:corrwith(metrix.loc[i[0]]))` Why there has a [0]? Thanks for your help!
The dataframe pre_df is looked like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQPEZ.png)

Comment: Your code is confusing try to edit it so it can be read more easily

Comment: `for i in metrix.index:`. Since `metrix` is MultiIndex, `i` is actually a pair. This, by the way, is a bad piece of code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, this should not be the way to go as it produces a lot of duplicates (looping through all the rows but only keep the first level). The function can be written as:

```
def calcCorr1(store, df):
    return pd.DataFrame({k:df.loc[store].corrwith(df.loc[k]) 
                         for k in df.index.unique('STORE_NBR')
                       }).T
```

Notice that instead of looping through all the rows, we just loop through the unique values in the first level (`STORE_NBR`) only. Since each store contains many rows, we are looking at a magnitude less of runtime here.